# Call an async method inside void C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Got a void function that saves data to DB, once the data has been saved I am trying to call a function that is going to send push notifications an it is supposed to be running ***async*** but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void Save(MyModel m)
    {
        using (var conn = Databases.DB)
        {
            var d = new DynamicParameters(new
            {
                m.Name
            });

            conn.Execute("INTRANET__CreateTicket", d, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            //send push notifications
            Task.Run(() => SendRaisedTicketNotifications(m));

        }
     }

    private async void SendRaisedTicketNotifications(NewAmbercatTicketView t)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Send push notifications
            var sub = new Subscritption();

            var people = UserRepository.List();
            foreach (var person in people)
            foreach (var sub in UserPushRepository.List().Where(x => x.PersonId == person.PersonId && x.Subscribed))
            {
                var notification = new PushNotification("Some content")
                notification.SendPushNotification(sub);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: `async void` is a bad practice. Use `async Task` instead

Comment: `Task.Run` appearing twice should already be ringing alarm bells. I'm also wondering why `SendRaisedTicketNotifications` doesn't appear to depend on its parameter at all.

Comment: What do you actually want to happen here? Are you just trying to call the method synchronously or are you wanting to run it as a background task? I'm not sure you know what async actually means.

Comment: are you trying to make the call  in fire and forget way ?   is this  what you  mean by async  .?

Comment: @DavidG All i wanna do is run the sending process in the background, so nothing is waiting for it to be finished, does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: Yes this is called fire and forget but you want to ensure that your push  notification was sent correctly?   is that right

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Yes that is quite right,

Comment: @NaughtyNinja have you tried  mocking it in a way that  you verify  that a notification is called

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Not sure I understand what you mean by that?

Comment: what you are doing seems correct  the only thing I  can suspect is that you have an issue in your pushnotification  for this reason the best way  is to mock  this

Answer (score 1):

How not to use `Task.Run` is covered by Stephen Cleary quite extensively in his [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html).

Since you do not want to wait for the async callback to finish, you could of course just start another Thread and forget about `Task.Run` alltogether since you make no practical use of the Task anyways.

```
public void Save(MyModel m)
{
    using (var conn = Databases.DB)
    {
        var d = new DynamicParameters(new
        {
            m.Name
        });

        conn.Execute("INTRANET__CreateTicket", d, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //send push notifications in BackgroundThread
        Thread sendInBackground = new Thread(new ParametrizedThreadStart(SendRaisedTicketNotifications));
        sendInBackground.IsBackground = true;
        sendInBackground.Start(m);

    }
 }

private void SendRaisedTicketNotifications(NewAmbercatTicketView t)
{
    //Send push notifications
    var sub = new Subscritption();

    var people = UserRepository.List();
    foreach (var person in people)
    foreach (var sub in UserPushRepository.List().Where(x => x.PersonId == person.PersonId && x.Subscribed))
    {
        var notification = new PushNotification("Some content")
        notification.SendPushNotification(sub);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this to send your notifications:

```
Task.Run(() => SendRaisedTicketNotifications(m)).Wait();
```

Comment: This will not run async but block the thread until the Task is completed.

Comment: But he asked, How to Call an async method inside void. And this is the only way as I know...